# In a private chain, is it possible to pre-mine a certain amount of ethers at a certain difficulty and then increase the difficulty level ?

Tags: go-ethereum, genesis

I want to run a private ethereum blockchain.

What I want is I want to distribute certain number of premined ethers (say 20 million) among some accounts. 
If I initially keep the difficulty high, It will take too long to mine the blocks and get the required rewards.

Is it possible to premine certain number of blocks and then increase the difficulty level? 
Will I have to stop the geth instance to adjust the difficulty level? 
and If I stop the geth instance in between, How can I continue mining over the previous blockchain with a different genesis blocK?

Comment: I think it would be simpler to pre-allocate funds to those accounts in the genesis block rather than forcing a step change in mining difficulty at a certain threshold - do you have any limitations that are preventing you from doing it this way?

Comment: The limitation is that I don't want to invest in expensive miners  till more miners join. But later,  I can't continue with a difficulty of something like 0x2000, because people may come up with powerful hardware and mine at an insane rate. and I also don't want to lose the previous transaction data at that point of time.

Comment: So in that case it seems more logical to set the difficulty where you want it at genesis and pre-allocate funds in the genesis block to certain addresses you control - you can do this by creating new accounts with geth before creating the genesis file, then running puppeth and pasting the addresses you'd like to pre-allocate funds to at the appropriate step of the genesis file creation

Comment: Append/add --fakepow to disable mining for geth command. But its not suggestible for live network.